# What Checksum/CRC algorithm in RF packet?

Tags: protocol, crc, networking

I am banging my head to figure out the checksum of a RF device, it seems to be a simple one but no luck so far...

The first 3 bytes is the SyncWord then 9 bytes is the payload and the last byte presumably is the checksum.

```
          +-------+-------+-------+-------+ ... +--------+--------+
          | byte0 | byte1 | byte2 | byte3 | ... | byte11 | byte12 |
          +-------+-------+-------+-------+ ... +--------+--------+
          <---- SyncWord (3) ----> <--- Payload (9) ----> <- CRC ->
```

It seems some kind of linear function but I cannot figure it out.

Any help will be appreciated!

#### Some ordered output

```
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0E,0xAA,0x70,0x30,0x30,0x96,0x84,0x27,0x13,0xF6
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0E,0xAA,0x60,0x30,0x30,0x96,0x84,0x27,0x13,0xE6
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x60,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x10
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x70,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x20
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0xAA,0x60,0x30,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x28
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0xAA,0x60,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x30
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0xAA,0x70,0x30,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x38

0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4F,0x8A,0x70,0x30,0x14,0x9C,0x81,0x25,0x12,0xFB
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4F,0xAA,0x70,0x30,0x14,0x9C,0x81,0x25,0x12,0x1B
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0E,0xAA,0x70,0x30,0x34,0x94,0x85,0x27,0x13,0xF9
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0E,0x8A,0x60,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x85,0x27,0x13,0xD1
```

#### Samples

```
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x74,0x39,0x15,0x9C,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x24
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0xAE,0x74,0x39,0x15,0x9C,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x04
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x74,0x39,0x15,0x9C,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x44
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x64,0x31,0x11,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x2A
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0x8E,0x74,0x31,0x11,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0xDA
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x74,0x31,0x11,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x1A
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x64,0x39,0x11,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x12
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0xAE,0x64,0x39,0x11,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0xF2
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x64,0x39,0x11,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x32
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x74,0x39,0x11,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x42
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0x8E,0x64,0x31,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0xCE
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x64,0x31,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x0E
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x74,0x31,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x1E
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0xAE,0x74,0x31,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0xFE
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x74,0x31,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x3E
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x64,0x39,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x36
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0x8E,0x74,0x39,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0xE6
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x74,0x39,0x15,0x9E,0x89,0x03,0x33,0x26
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x64,0x31,0x11,0x9C,0x88,0x03,0xB3,0x87
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0xAE,0x64,0x31,0x11,0x9C,0x88,0x03,0xB3,0x67
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x64,0x31,0x11,0x9C,0x88,0x03,0xB3,0xA7
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0xAE,0x74,0x31,0x11,0x9C,0x88,0x03,0xB3,0xB7
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1F,0x8E,0x64,0x39,0x11,0x9C,0x88,0x03,0xB3,0x4F
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5F,0x8E,0x64,0x39,0x11,0x9C,0x88,0x03,0xB3,0x8F

0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5E,0x0F,0x24,0x91,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x75
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x24,0x91,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x55
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x34,0x91,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x65
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5E,0x2F,0x34,0x91,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0xA5
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x0F,0x24,0x99,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x3D
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x0F,0x34,0x99,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x4D
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5E,0x0F,0x34,0x99,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x8D
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x34,0x99,0x01,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x6D
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x24,0x91,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x59
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5E,0x2F,0x24,0x91,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x99
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x0F,0x34,0x91,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x49
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x0F,0x24,0x99,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x41
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5E,0x0F,0x24,0x99,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x81
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x24,0x99,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x61
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x34,0x99,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0x71
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5E,0x2F,0x34,0x99,0x05,0x86,0x81,0x01,0x30,0xB1
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x0F,0x24,0x91,0x01,0x84,0x80,0x01,0xB0,0xB2
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x0F,0x34,0x91,0x01,0x84,0x80,0x01,0xB0,0xC2
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x5E,0x0F,0x34,0x91,0x01,0x84,0x80,0x01,0xB0,0x02
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x34,0x91,0x01,0x84,0x80,0x01,0xB0,0xE2
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x1E,0x2F,0x24,0x99,0x01,0x84,0x80,0x01,0xB0,0xDA

0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0F,0xAA,0x60,0x30,0x14,0x9C,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xD1
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0F,0xAA,0x70,0x30,0x14,0x9C,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xE1
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0F,0x8A,0x70,0x30,0x14,0x9C,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xC1
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0F,0x8A,0x60,0x38,0x14,0x9C,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xB9
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0F,0xAA,0x60,0x38,0x14,0x9C,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xD9
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0F,0x8A,0x70,0x38,0x14,0x9C,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xC9
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0F,0x8A,0x60,0x30,0x10,0x9E,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xAF
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4F,0xAA,0x60,0x30,0x10,0x9E,0x88,0x23,0x13,0x0F
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4F,0x8A,0x70,0x30,0x10,0x9E,0x88,0x23,0x13,0xFF
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0xAA,0x60,0x30,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x28
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x70,0x30,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x18
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0xAA,0x70,0x30,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x38
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x60,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x10
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0xAA,0x60,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x30
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x70,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x20
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x60,0x30,0x30,0x96,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x06
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0E,0xAA,0x60,0x30,0x30,0x96,0x84,0x27,0x13,0xE6
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0E,0x8A,0x70,0x30,0x30,0x96,0x84,0x27,0x13,0xD6
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x0E,0xAA,0x70,0x30,0x30,0x96,0x84,0x27,0x13,0xF6
```

Comment: can you extract code from the device, or is there a firmware update available? similar question about the receiving side.

Comment: Its a PIC mcu no firmware available and code protection bit enabled, receiver is the same. The rf side is a cc1101, but none of its packet control feature enabled, so they are handling everything in the pic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checksum algorithm is simple indeed. It adds all the payload bytes modulo 0xFF and then adds 26.

I wrote a script to test it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import binascii

def checksum(data):
    payload = data[3:-1]
    checksum = 26
    for c in payload:
        checksum += c
    checksum &= 0xFF
    return checksum

with open("input.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line == "":
            continue
        line = line.replace(",","")
        line = line.replace("0x","")

        data = binascii.unhexlify(line)

        if checksum(data) == data[-1]:
            print("pass")
        else:
            print("fail")
```

I copied your above samples into `input.txt` and they all passed.

As for how I found out, I googled about sync words (didn't know what that is), and 1 byte checksums and some other post mentioned simple addition. I also tested multiple CRC8 variants but none worked. I also found it telling that the checksum seems to reflect changes in the input, such as:

```
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x60,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x10
0xE1,0xC0,0x0A,0x4E,0x8A,0x70,0x38,0x34,0x94,0x84,0x27,0x13,0x20
```

The `0x60` changed to `0x70` and so did the checksum increase by `0x10` which - I think - would not be as obvious for CRCs.

Comment: Thank You! I really appreciate your time, and i also tested this algorithm with slight modification and indeed works like a charm.

Comment: @RáczAttila what modification did you have to make?

Comment: Because i used python2.7 the binascii method not worked. I had to use data= line.split(",") and checksum += int(c,16).